# Quotient-Remainder Theorem Proving

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

This theorem is obviously correct. Now I try to prove it by well-ordering principle.

But I don't know where to start the proving....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Theorem:** For every pair of integers $a,b$ where $b≠0$, there exists unique integers $q,r$ such that $a=qb+r$ and $0≤r<|b|$.

**Existence**

Consider the following progression:
$$…,a−3b,a−2b,a−b,a,a+b,a+2b,a+3b,…$$
This extends in both directions. By the **Well-Ordering Principle**, there must exist a smallest non-negative element, $x$.
Thus, $x=a−qb$ for some $q∈\mathbb{Z}$.
$x$ must be in the interval $[0,b)$ because otherwise $r−b$ would be smaller than $r$ and a non-negative element in the progression.

**Uniqueness**

Suppose we have another pair $q_0$ and $r_0$ such that $a=bq_0+r_0$, with $0≤r_0<b$.
$$ bq+r=bq_0+r_0.$$
We see that $r−r_0=b(q_0−q)$, and so $b\setminus (r−r_0)$. Since $0≤r<b$ and $0≤r_0<b$, we have that $−b<r−r_0<b.$ Hence, $r−r_0=0\implies r=r_0$. So $r−r_0=0=b(q_0−q)$ which implies that $q=q_0$. This shows uniqueness.

For an alternative proof, see http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/shirley/a325k/Handouts/induction%20and%20wop/q-r-theorem-proof.pdf.

Comment: It helps. Thank you so much

Comment: @SonicFancy Sure!

Comment: I don't understand your proof of uniqueness. How do you conclude $r - r_0 = 0$?

Comment: @shuhalo because $r-r_0$ is a multiple of $b$ and it also is greater  than $-b$ and smaller than $b$, hence the only multiple it can be is zero

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\,S\subset \Bbb Z \,$ and $\,0<b\in\Bbb Z.\,$ If $\,S\,$ has a nonnegative integer $\,a,\,$  and $\,n\in S\,\Rightarrow\,n\!-\!b\in S\,$ then $\,S\,$ has least nonnegative element $\,\ell < b\,$ (otherwise $\,\ell\!-\!b\in S\,$ and $\,0 < \ell\! -\!b < \ell,\,$ contra minimality of $\,\ell).\,$  Therefore if $\ a\ge 0\,$ then $\,S = a-b\,\Bbb Z\,$ has least nonnegative element $< b.$